# Azure Service Fabric: Unprovision application version

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm looking for a way of cleaning old application versions in Service Fabric via the SDK. It seems there is no way to unprovision a version by using `FabricClient`'s `ApplicationManager` (similar to the action available in the Service Fabric Explorer, Application Type view) ?

I can get a list of all the versions for an application type by using: `fabricClient.QueryManager.GetApplicationTypeListAsync()`

Comment: This is now supported by Service Fabric; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61348767/2078866)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.applicationmanagementclient.unprovisionapplicationasync?view=servicefabric-5.5.216#System_Fabric_FabricClient_ApplicationManagementClient_UnprovisionApplicationAsync_System_String_System_String_):

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task UnprovisionApplicationAsync (string applicationTypeName, string applicationTypeVersion);
```

> Unregisters and removes a Service Fabric application type from the
>   cluster.

Comment: this works for unprovisioning a version, however the corresponding folder on the disk is not deleted

Answer (score 1):

SF performes a regular sync on the nodes, so after a while the folders on the disk for the unprovisioned versions will be cleaned.