# Unprovision type in Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

In order to uninstall an application in `Service Fabric`, I need a workflow similar to the one in the Explorer: Delete Application and then Unprovision Type.

While `FabricClient`'s `ApplicationManager` has a `DeleteApplicationAsync` method, there doesn't seem to be any way to `Unprovision` or `Unregister` for the type.

The [Azure docs on github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications-fabricclient.md) mention a cmdlet called `Unregister-ServiceFabricApplicationType`, however the links in that doc are all broken.

Is it possible to unprovision the type via `FabricClient`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Service Fabric: Unprovision application version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114543/azure-service-fabric-unprovision-application-version)

Comment: No, that one it's about removing a specific app version

Comment: Removing all versions also removes the type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Unprovision​Application​Async method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.applicationmanagementclient.unprovisionapplicationasync?view=azure-dotnet) to unprovision the application type.  [Deploy and remove applications using FabricClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications-fabricclient) has an example.

Comment: You're right, calling UnprovisionApplicationAsync for every existing version will eventually unprovision the type.